# How to get Exchange Identity Token in JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net, office365, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices

Outlook API returns "an identity token" using `Office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync(callback, userContext);` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142236.aspx). I'm trying to get the JSON out of the base-64 URL encoded string.

So far I've tried the sample of code from this url : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7f4813a-3b2d-47bb-bf93-71b64620a56b

**Javascript:**

```
Office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync(function (data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/exchange/createAndValidateIdentityToken",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ userIdentityToken: data.value })
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

**C#:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public AppIdentityToken CreateAndValidateIdentityToken(JObject data)
    {
        JToken userIdentityToken = data.GetValue("userIdentityToken");
        string rawToken = userIdentityToken.Value<string>();

        try
        {
            AppIdentityToken token = (AppIdentityToken)AuthToken.Parse(rawToken);
            token.Validate(new Uri("https://**url**/ews/exchange.asmx"));

            return token;
        }
        catch (TokenValidationException ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("A client identity token validation error occurred.", ex);
        }

    }
```

The `AuthToken.Parse` returns an `AppIdentityToken` full of exceptions and I don't understand why:

[image: Error IdentityToken]

**Note1:** Errors are partly in French : "a levé une exception de type" = "has raised an exception of type".

**Note2:** Identity token format when decoded : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179838.aspx

Comment: These exceptions are called if the token members are accessed prior to calling the Validate method.  What happens if you inspect the token AFTER calling the Validate method?

Comment: When I jump from the `token.Validate` line, it goes to the `catch` line : "A client identity token validation error occurred." InnerException: "Audience URI validation failed. Audience does not match." I guess the URI is wrong then, what URI are they looking for ? It's very unclear on the documentation.

Comment: That's a validation error.  Looks like the supplied URI and expected URI don't match.

Comment: That would I would only be guessing at, but you might want to begin your search here...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568639(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't understand the link with the URI. Where does this XML comes from ?

Comment: @Elfayer: Yes, the documentation is horribly incomplete. The url that they are looking for is the url of the Outlook add-in without query parameters, in some parts of the documentation it is called "audience url". 
This works for me:
`var audienceUrl = location.href.split('?')[0];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution after a whole day of searching. Here are the sources that led me to the solution :

This link say that in case of an `InvalidTokenAudienceException`:

> Contains the exception thrown when the URL passed to the Validate()
>   method of the AppIdentityToken object does not match **the audience
>   parameter specified in the client identity token.**
>   (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.auth.validation(v=exchg.80).aspx)

In the JSON identity token, there is an `aud` attribute that takes a .html file, and :

> A token is only valid if it is sent from the add-in that is running in
>   the client's browser. **If the add-in uses the Office Add-ins manifests
>   schema v1.1, this URL is the URL specified in the first SourceLocation
>   element, under the form type ItemRead or ItemEdit**
>   (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179838.aspx)

The following code works for me :

```
[HttpPost]
public AppIdentityToken CreateAndValidateIdentityToken(JObject data)
    {
        JToken userIdentityToken = data.GetValue("userIdentityToken");
        string rawToken = userIdentityToken.Value<string>();

        try
        {
            AppIdentityToken token = (AppIdentityToken)AuthToken.Parse(rawToken);
            token.Validate(new Uri("https://localhost:44300/AppRead/Home/Home.html"));

            return token;
        }
        catch (TokenValidationException ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("A client identity token validation error occurred.", ex);
        }

    }
```